# Pandas dataframe how to make element-wise mean of list columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-munging

I have a dataframe with categorical features and values features.
Value features are always lists with the exact same size (let's say 3 for the example).
So the dataframe is:

```
Sub Model iter key     l1       l2     l3
 01  b     0    0    [8,8,5] [3,8,1] [6,7,8]
 01  b     1    1    [4,3,6] [3,4,0] [4,0,4]
 01  b     2    2    [0,1,4] [0,0,5] [8,2,3]
 03  b     3    0    [1,8,2] [4,6,0] [1,3,9]
 03  b     4    1    [7,3,1] [6,8,1] [6,7,9]
 03  b     5    2    [1,1,0] [11,4,8] [8,5,9]
```

I want to group the dataframe by `[sub,model]`, such that in each row I will take the mean over the values of the columns key.
So I will get:

```
Sub  Model     l1         l2       l3 
 01   b      [4, 4, 5]  [2,2,2]   [6,3,5]
 03   b      [3, 4, 1]  [7,6,3]   [3,5,9]
```

What will be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agg` and a custom function:

```
def mean_list(sr):
    return sr.apply(pd.Series).mean()

out = df.groupby(['Sub', 'Model'])[['l1', 'l2', 'l3']].agg(mean_list)
```

```
>>> out
                        l1               l2               l3
Sub Model
01  b      [4.0, 4.0, 5.0]  [2.0, 4.0, 2.0]  [6.0, 3.0, 5.0]
03  b      [3.0, 4.0, 1.0]  [7.0, 6.0, 3.0]  [5.0, 5.0, 9.0]
```

Comment: You're missing a `'` ;) +1 I always liked custom functions

Comment: @Corralien I get the error {ValueError}Function does not reduce , any idea why?

Comment: Update your post with  a sample of your real dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet:

```
(df.groupby(['Sub', 'Model'])
   [['l1', 'l2', 'l3']]
   .apply(lambda d: pd.Series({c: np.array([*d[c].values]).mean(0)
                               for c in d.columns}))
)
```

output:

```
                        l1               l2               l3
Sub Model                                                   
01  b      [4.0, 4.0, 5.0]  [2.0, 4.0, 2.0]  [6.0, 3.0, 5.0]
03  b      [3.0, 4.0, 1.0]  [7.0, 6.0, 3.0]  [5.0, 5.0, 9.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) together with [`np.mean()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html), as follows:

```
import numpy as np

(df.groupby(['Sub', 'Model'])[['l1', 'l2', 'l3']]
   .agg(lambda x: np.mean(x.values.tolist(), axis=0)).reset_index()
)
```

**Result:**

```
  Sub Model               l1               l2               l3
0  01     b  [4.0, 4.0, 5.0]  [2.0, 4.0, 2.0]  [6.0, 3.0, 5.0]
1  03     b  [3.0, 4.0, 1.0]  [7.0, 6.0, 3.0]  [5.0, 5.0, 9.0]
```

### Edit:

If your `l1`, `l2`, `l3` are actually strings look like lists, you can do the following before the solution codes:

```
df['l1'] = df['l1'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',', expand=True).astype(int).apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1)
df['l2'] = df['l2'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',', expand=True).astype(int).apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1)
df['l3'] = df['l3'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',', expand=True).astype(int).apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: I get the error {ValueError}Function does not reduce , any idea why?

Comment: @okuoub  Are the lists real lists or strings look like list ?  Can you post the `df.to_dict()` output to the question ?

Comment: @okuoub  See my edit with codes to convert strings looking like lists to real lists.  You can try it.